# print consecutive lines conditional on two fields and substract another fied

Tags: awk, field, line, matching

I would like to print consecutive lines if they have matching first field but opposite signal in third field. Then compute the distance between the second fields of consecutive lines.

Input:

```
id1 pos1 0.19
id1 pos2 0.33
id1 pos3 -0.25
id1 pos4 -0.22
id2 pos5 0.33
id3 pos6 -0.21
id3 pos7 -0.56
id3 pos8 -0.20
id3 pos9 0.33
id3 pos10 -0.32
```

Intermediate output:

```
id1 pos2 0.33
id1 pos3 -0.25
id3 pos8 -0.20
id3 pos9 0.33
id3 pos10 -0.32
```

Desired output:

```
id1 pos3-pos2
id3 pos9-pos8
id3 pos10-pos9
```

I found similar questions comparing consecutive lines but none can be applied to answer my question.

So far I tried:

```
awk '$1==prev1{$NF=$2-prev2;print $1,$NF} {prev2=$2;prev1=$1}'
```

But I do not know how to add the condition of third field must have opposite signal.

Comment: Why this output `id3 pos8 -0.20` when previous is `id3 pos7 -0.56` also a negative value?  By opposite signal, do you go from + to - ?

Comment: if the first field is the same (same id) with the previous line and the third field value is negative in the previous line but current line is positive (or viceversa), then substract field 2 of previous line from the current line. (field 2 is position)

Comment: I have updated my post.  It now look at change from + to - and from - to + within same ID

Answer (score 2):

From your description this `awk` should do:

```
awk '{sc=$3~/^-/?0:1} $1==p1&&sp!=sc {print $1,($3-p3)} {sp=sc;p1=$1;p3=$3}' file
id1 -0.58
id3 0.53
id3 -0.65
```

`sc=$3~/^-/?0:1` test if value is positive `1` or negative `0`
`$1==p1&&sp!=sc` If current ID is equal previous ID and value change sign,
`print $1,($3-p3)` print ID and differential between current and previous value.
 `sp=sc;p1=$1;p3=$3` set previous: sp to sc, p1 to $1 and p3 to $3

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
prev!=$1{
  prev_val=prev=""
}
prev==$1{
  if(($NF~/^-/ && prev_val!~/^-/) || ($NF!~/^-/ && prev_val~/^-/)){
     print $1,$2,$NF-prev_val
  }
}
{
  prev=$1
  prev_val=$NF
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: I would like to substact field 2 not field 4.

Comment: @AEC, Sorry didn't get it, there is no field 4 mentioned in code, `$NF` means last field of the line.

Comment: sorry I wanted to say field3 instead of field4. In your case I do not want to substract $NF but $2. But I already know how to do it, very similar to your code above.

Comment: @AEC, I don't understand, your sample shows `$3`(3rd field) if your Input_file doesn't have it you could try changing it once and let me know then.

Answer (score -2):

```
awk  'prev1!=$1{
  prev3=prev2=prev1=""
}
prev1==$1{
  if(($3~/^-/ && prev3!~/^-/) || ($3!~/^-/ && prev3~/^-/)){
     print $1,$2-prev2
  }
}
{
  prev1=$1
  prev2=$2
  prev3=$3
}
'  Input
```

This is the answer to my question. Thanks to all for helping me.

Comment: You could have edited my answer by adding this one ++ could select that answer correct one too.